# cakephp select statement with left join

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables are `Servers` and `ApplicationsGroupsServers`, where `server_id` is foreign key to `Servers.id`.

I am trying to write a query to select a field called server_name from servers table and left join all data from `ApplicationsGroupsServers` table.

```
$option = array(
    'join' => array(
            'table' => 'Servers',
            'alias' => 's',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array( 's.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.id' )
        )
);
$apps = $this->ApplicationsGroupsServers->find('all', array(
    "fields" => array('Servers.server_name'), ($option)
));
$this->set('applications', $apps);
```

But, when I run a query like shown below. I am able to populate results:

```
$apps = $this->ApplicationsGroupsServers->find('all', $option);
```

SQL Query in the back end that runs:

```
SELECT ApplicationsGroupsServers.id AS `ApplicationsGroupsServers__id`, 
    ApplicationsGroupsServers.application_id AS `ApplicationsGroupsServers__application_id`, 
    ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id AS `ApplicationsGroupsServers__group_id`, 
    ApplicationsGroupsServers.server_id AS `ApplicationsGroupsServers__server_id` 
FROM applications_groups_servers ApplicationsGroupsServers 
     left JOIN Servers s ON s.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.id
```

However, I am trying to run something like this:

```
SELECT server_name
  FROM applications_groups_servers
       LEFT JOIN servers
          ON servers.id = applications_groups_servers.server_id
       LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = applications_groups_servers.group_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create relationships between your models instead of using `join` queries, but if you really want to use a `join` query:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Server.name' // Server not Servers
    ),
    'join' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'servers',
            'alias' => 'Server',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Server.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.server_id',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Group.id = ApplicationsGroupsServers.group_id',
            )
        )
    )
) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Holt. I do have a relationships in my models. In ApplicationsGroupsServersTable I have a belongs to relationship to ServersTable. Here is the relationship in for ApplicationsGroupsServers:  `$this->belongsTo('Servers', ['foreignKey' => 'server_id']);`

Comment: I also tried above solution, but it only gives me all the record from ApplicationsGroupsServers table and nothing from Servers table. Here is what I get in return `[{"id":1,"application_id":1,"group_id":1,"server_id":1},{"id":3,"application_id":2,"group_id":2,"server_id":2}]`

Comment: @Ray If you did a copy/paste, there was a typo (`field` instead of `fields`), if not could you show the query you get by running this?

Comment: thank you so much, I didnt noticed that at all. It works now :)

Comment: I have one more question. If I want to add another field and get col from another table, I will do like this right:   array(
    `'fields' => array(
        'Server.name', // Server not Servers
        'Group.group_name'
    )`

Comment: @Ray Yes, if the field is accessible through your join (e.g. `Group.name`) it will be available using the `fields` option.

Comment: When I run it, I get  `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Group.name' in 'field list'` I have also made sure that association is in plave between Groups table and ApplicationsGroupsServers table.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
$this->Server->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->Server->bindModel(array('ApplicationsGroups'=>array('classname'=>'ApplicationsGroupsServer','foriegnKey'=>'server_id')));
$app=$this->Server->find(all,array('contain'=>array('ApplicationsGroupsServer.server_name')));
```

Comment: Did you look at this answer after writing it? Please format/indent your code, an explanation rather than just a code dump would also be a good idea.

Comment: Ash, I am currently working on ApplicationsGroupsServersController. For your solution, I might have to switch to ServersController, I believe.